# Need to take div element remaing width when using float left

Tags: css

This is my code and my expectation. Please give any good suggestion.

```css
.dash-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.dash-wrapper > div {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.dash-nav{
  background-color: #606B79;
  max-width:223px;
  width: 25%;
}

.dash-content{
  width:??????;
  }
```

```html
<div class="dash-wrapper">
  <div class="dash-nav">
  </div>
  <div class="dash-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to take `.dash-content` remaining width after reducing `dash-nav` width ( It will be 25% but maximum width is 223px ). So If I put 75% width I am getting extra space in the container for large view port devices. For smaller devices it will work I know. I want to use remaining width in the all the view port. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use calc then add this inside your style tag:

```
    .dash-content {
        background-color: #F00;
        width: 75%;
    }
    //have to change this by a few pixels to handle all screen widths
    @media only screen and (min-width: 994px) {

        .dash-content {
            width: calc(100% - 223px);
        }
    }
```

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is support for calc...

If you can't use it, try this solution (might point you in right direction):

```css
    .dash-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px; /*made this 100px to show in snippet, change to %*/
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

        .dash-wrapper > div {
            height: 100%;
        }

    .dash-nav {
        background-color: #606B79;
        max-width: 223px;
        width: 25%;
    }

    .dash-content {
        width: auto;
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dash-wrapper">
  <div class="dash-nav">
  </div>
  <div class="dash-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.dash-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.dash-nav {
  background-color: #606B79;
  max-width: 223px;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
.dash-content {
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<div class="dash-wrapper">
  <div class="dash-nav">
  </div>
  <div class="dash-content">
  </div>
</div>
```